# Extracting strings based on a particular split delimiter in php

Tags: php, extract

I have a string `"test@html.com+test+7"`.I want to extract `test@html.com`, `test` and `7` into an array. How to achieve this is PHP? I have tried using `preg_match` but couldn't crack it.

Comment: If the + character always means another string, use the explode function..

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Yes.I have used explode('+',s) and its working fine.Thanks dieter and billy.

Answer (score 1):

```
print_r(explode("+","test@html.com+test+7"));
```

[working code :)](http://codepad.org/VGRChyFI)